# Control specific audio output like, decrease audio from browser in Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

I need to reduce the volume of a radio that plays in the browser, play a song in my Electron app, then raise the radio volume in the browser again. Is it possible to do it on Electron?

I searched for a library that made isos but I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

## Explained

You could simply do it via the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/volume) within a [renderer process](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer), **keep in mind**, you wouldn't be able to approach the problem like this if you desire to handle volume within the [main process](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main), simply because you cannot access the DOM within the main process.

I mean this may not be the best way, however, it's a simple way, at least in my opinion, and it saves having to include anymore dependencies into the project. Thus in my opinion, possibly making it more stable & reliable, with this approach, you wouldn't have to worry about 'x' dependency changing, expect for Electron itself. I **may** even go as far to say that it **could** also mean that it's more performance friendly, as you don't need to load in another dependency, although I'm not confident enough to say that all of this is a solid fact, **this is, for the most part, opinion based**.